# (Swift 4) How to generate custom auto id in firebase?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, swift4, userid

How to generate custom auto id in Firebase?
I using swift 4.

now my project when sign up a user in firebase. the id will like this: 
user_id: 25ERcRyKtAR5IYPBI9XzJLu8I3F2

I need to set up a search center for admin so i need to make the id sample.

I want the id like this: (start with (18xxxxxx) and 8 number.)

```
user_id: 18435237
user_id: 18947232
user_id: 18451323
user_id: 18749325
```

Comment: Sounds like a pretty clear use-case. What's the problem you have while implementing it?

Comment: I can't custom the user id  when use  Auth() to create user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UID of a user account is determined by the provider that mints the tokens for that user account. There is no way to control the UIDs generated by any of the existing Firebase Authentication providers.

If you want to control the UID, you'll have to create your own provider as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth

I'd recommend against this though, and consider: what you are trying to accomplish by controlling the UID, and seeing if there's another way to accomplish this. Right now it reads like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and above is the best I can tell you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. now I using a special solution to fix this problem. I set the Auth().displayName to 8 random Int. The Real username will store in RealTimeDB. The user table from RealTimeDB will be that 8 random Int. haha~ This is the only solution i can do and this is work. The Auth and RealTimeDB have connection and i can keep the 8 random Int be uid.

Comment: As I already said, it sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which is really hard to help with if you don't tell us what X is. It's good to hear that you found something that works for you though. 